# How to get values only from the 1st level of JSON text in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table like this

```
class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Citys'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    metadatas = Column(String)
```

with these values

```
id=1, name="London", metadatas='{"lat":51.5072, "lon":0.1276, "Mayor": "Sadiq Khan", "participating":true, "apps":{"Facebook": {"messenger": true}, "Instagram":{"message":false}}}',
id=2, name="Liverpool", metadatas='{"lat":53.4084, "lon":2.9916, "Mayor": "Joanne Anderson", "participating":false, "apps":{"Twitter": {"messenger": true}, "telegram":{"message":false}}}',
id=3, name="Manchester", metadatas='{"lat":53.4808, "lon":2.2426, "Mayor": "Donna Ludford", "participating":true, "apps":{"TikTok": {"messenger": true}, "Google Meet":{"message":false}}}')]
```

the column `metadatas` is in json text format.

I want to implement a functionality that when a user searches for the app name it should return the id, name and metadatas related to it that filter app name.

for example if my search query is `Facebook` then it should return something like this

```
1 London {"lat":51.5072, "lon":0.1276, "Mayor": "Sadiq Khan", "participating":true, "apps":{"Facebook": {"messenger": true}, "Instagram":{"message":false}}}
```

if the user searches for something like `message` it shouldn't return anything.

Here's what I have implemented

```
filtered_query = session.query(Citys).filter(
    func.json_extract(Citys.metadatas, '$.apps').cast(String).like('%' + 'Facebook' + '%')).all()
```

and this returns me

```
1 London {"lat":51.5072, "lon":0.1276, "Mayor": "Sadiq Khan", "participating":true, "apps":{"Facebook": {"messenger": true}, "Instagram":{"message":false}}}
```

but when I search for `message` it returns

```
1 London {"lat":51.5072, "lon":0.1276, "Mayor": "Sadiq Khan", "participating":true, "apps":{"Facebook": {"messenger": true}, "Instagram":{"message":false}}}
2 Liverpool {"lat":53.4084, "lon":2.9916, "Mayor": "Joanne Anderson", "participating":false, "apps":{"vonage": {"messenger": true}, "telegram":{"message":false}}}
3 Manchester {"lat":53.4808, "lon":2.2426, "Mayor": "Donna Ludford", "participating":true, "apps":{"TikTok": {"messenger": true}, "Meet":{"message":false}}}
```

which is not my desired result for the second search query it should return empty data

Comment: @python_user - mysql

Comment: @python_user, any way to get the solution?

Comment: not really sure, have you tried using `json_contains_path` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned you can use [`json_contains_path`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains-path) like so

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    search_key = "Facebook"

    filtered_query = (
        session.query(City)
        .filter(
            func.json_contains_path(City.metadatas, "one", f'$.apps."{search_key}"')
        )
        .all()
    )

    for i in filtered_query:
        print(i.name)
```

Output

`London`

If I change `search_key` to `message`, as expected, I get nothing.